# Create running files in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and I need help.

This is a client side folder (source code):
https://ibb.co/mv3SYTm

but this is the client folder - the actually run files on the server:
https://ibb.co/yW8CJPp.

How do I produce these files and how do i run them on server?

Note:
It may be related to "fe", but I do not know what exactly that means.

Thanks

Comment: I downvoted because: [image of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), [no attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), [no research](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/). Those files are generated by [AOT compiler](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/). See [build command](https://angular.io/cli#command-overview)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. please view the official document. https://angular.io/. You can make rigging as angular build on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna think you have Angular CLI installed ([Link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli)). Open a terminal / CMD on windows and type `ng build --prod` if you have production variables. Afterwards, if you want to deploy the app to a server you will have to get the builded files from `/dist`. Then depending on the server, the method may vary, but the most common method is that you just have to copy/paste those files.